# Display radio button checked if json value is match to condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I've following Json data

{"1":"2","2":"2"} this can be change as per conditions.

I'm trying to implement radio button checked if Json contain value same as radio button.
in Json first Value is radio name and 2nd is value that needs to match.

```
 success : function(result){
        //alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        var contact = JSON.parse(result);
        alert("First: " + contact + " Second: " + contact);
        $('input[type=radio][name="' + group[contact[1]] + '"][value="' + contact[1] + '"]').prop('checked', true);


        }
```

Following is my html form

```
<table width="50%" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" >




<th><td colspan='2'> <font color='#006699' size='3' face='Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif'><strong>    Assign User Role </br></br></strong></font></td></th>


 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td><strong>Select User:</strong></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="assigned_to" id="assigned_to" /></td>
 </tr>

<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td><strong>Page Group</strong></td>
    <td><strong>User Role </strong></td> 
</tr>






    <?php
    foreach($groups as $key=>$value) 
    { ?>    
        <tr bgcolor='#FFFFFF'>
        <td><strong><?php echo $value; ?></strong></td>
        <td>
        <input type="radio" name="group[<?php echo $key; ?>]"  id="chk_group1" value="1" />Viewer
        <input type="radio" name="group[<?php echo $key; ?>]"  id="chk_group2"  value="2" />Approver
        <input type="radio" name="group[<?php echo $key; ?>]"  id="chk_group3" value="3" />Editor
        <input type="radio" name="group[<?php echo $key; ?>]"  id="chk_group3" value="4" />Adder
        <input type="radio" name="group[<?php echo $key; ?>]"  id="chk_group4" value="5" />Super Editor
        <input type="radio" name="group[<?php echo $key; ?>]"  id="chk_group5" value="6" />Blocked
        </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    } 
    ?>


 </tr>
 <tr></tr> <tr></tr> <tr></tr>
 <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You don't need to use `JSON.parse(result);`. `result` parameter in `success` handler is a JSON ready to use.

Comment: Can you please give me sample code, as I'm new to Json, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse through radio elements collection using each() of jquery, check for matched radio value with json provided value and add check to matched radio.

According to your json as :

```
{"1":"2","2":"2"}
```

Insert below code in sucess function of ajax

```
success : function(result){
        for(key in result){
         $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
           if($(this).val() === result[key]){
              $(this).prop('checked', true);
           }
         }
        }
}
```

Comment: user3300466, you may implement above code and modify as per your requirements :)

Comment: Not working, I tried to alert(contact[key]) but no hope;

Comment: Check for the result, what it returns. Does it in your given json format?

Comment: Lets take example with javascript variable                          var contact = {"1":"1", "2":"2"}; If you apply for in loop as    for(key in contact){alert(contact[key])} It will show alerts along with the values :)

Comment: when I tried without json parse  `code` for(key in result){
    
    alert(key[0]);
    alert(val);
    //$('input[type=radio]input[name=group"'+key[0]+'"] [value="' + key[1] + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    }   now i'm only gettig key

Comment: When you loop through result, key is just like index we use in array. You need to do result[key] not key[0 or 1] for fetching respective value. Hence your code will be : for(key in result){ alert(result[key]);} // where result[key] will be your required value

Comment: Yes buddy; now its working. please change your answer according. Thanks a ton :-)

Comment: I have updated my answer, if helpful then accept it :)

Comment: Hope this will be helpful... :)